# how to disable the rest all items in multiSelect box

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

Once an item is selected, how to disable the rest all items in multiSelect box. So that multiple items should not be selected. Multiselect box display values are:00.00A.M...11.00pm. For ex: if 01.00 am is selected rest all should be disabled though restricted to 1 selection box gets expanded double the existing width. following properties were used:

```
                            xtype:'multiselect',
                            id:'fromMultiselect',
                            name:'fromMultiselect',
                            columnWidth: .33,
                            maxSelections:1,
                            initValues : true,
                            hideLabel : true,
                            width : 130,
                            height : 90,
                            allowBlank : false,
                            disabled: false,
                            mode:'local',
                            store : FromTimeStore ,
                            valueField : 'id',
                            displayField : 'displayFromTime',
                            columnWidth: .32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use combobox with multiselect:false and expand it after render?

Nevetheless you can still use multiselect:
add option:  `maxSelections: 1,`

Example here (you must uncomment maxSelections property):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.js

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

Comment: thnx but not clear with first one (need an example)..rest were helpful.